# Access inner DropDownList.SelectedValue of GridView using CommandArgument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I want to set "Visible = true" to the TextBox "eventnoteAddTextBox" in GridView when the value of DropDownList "eventnoteEditDrpDwnLst" is set to "Custom..."

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server"
...
    OnRowCommand="grid_RowCommand"
    ShowFooter="True">
<columns>
...
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Event">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="eventnoteLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eventnote") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="eventnoteEditDrpDwnLst" runat="server" DataTextField="eventnote" DataValueField="eventnote"></asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst" runat="server" DataTextField="eventnote" DataValueField="eventnote" CommandName="AddCustomEventNote" CommandArgument="<%# ??? eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst.SelectedText ??? %>"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="eventnoteAddUpdatePanel" runat="server" RenderMode="Block">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="eventnoteAddTextBox" runat="server" DataTextField="eventnote" DataValueField="eventnote" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code-behind

```
protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddCustomEventNote"))
    {
        DropDownList eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst = (DropDownList)e.CommandSource;
        if (eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst.SelectedValue == "Custom...")
            Response.Write("<script>alert('It works!');</script>");
            //grid.FooterRow.FindControl("eventnoteAddTextBox").Visible = true;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddCustomEventNote"))
    {
        DropDownList eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst = (DropDownList)grid.FooterRow.FindControl("eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst");

        string value = eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what to put as "CommandArgument" in <asp:DropDownList> as well. Should it be empty?!

Comment: It should be empty, since you don't want a static value, you want the value selected in the dropdown. The `CommandArgument` would make sense if it was a button or something that could have a static value that was the sender, but not with a dropdown (unless you need some extra value, besides the value in the selected item).

Comment: Seems it doesn't work at all. Look, I edited a bit to be more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that the control was in the footer row. I updated my answer. Try that instead.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. Finally I've got the solution. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there should be AutoPostBack and a separate invoke-function for `<asp:DropDownList>`. It can be covered with `<asp:UpdatePanel RenderMode="Block">` and `<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true">` as well to act smooth.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst" runat="server" DataTextField="eventnote" DataValueField="eventnote" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Code-behind goes as simple as:

```
protected void eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst = (DropDownList)grid.FooterRow.FindControl("eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst");
        if (eventnoteAddDrpDwnLst.SelectedValue == "Custom...")
            grid.FooterRow.FindControl("eventnoteAddTextBox").Visible = true;
        else
            grid.FooterRow.FindControl("eventnoteAddTextBox").Visible = false;
    }
```

It really works! **DropDownList doesn't have CommandArgument!**